# bash scripts execution in different terminals

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash scripts, which I execute from new terminal every time I want to start my project

`celery.sh`

```
activate () {
     . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
}
activate
cd projectname
celery -A projectname worker -l info
```

`flower.sh`

```
activate () {
     . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
}
activate
cd projectname
celery -A projectname flower --port=5555
```

`start.sh`

```
activate () {
     . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
}
activate
cd projectname
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

this scripts are used on my local machine, and i `execute` them with `3 different commands` each command in `new terminal`

`./celery.sh`

`./flower.sh`

`./start.sh`

I found it boring, and `redundant` that i'm forced to open this 3 terminals each time.

`My goal` is to create one script `./ultimatestart.sh` which will start `all of this three scripts`, each of which should be `opened in its personal terminal`

> Answer update, thanks to Olaf Kock i found out the solution for my MacOs and zsh terminal

i have two options, first which will start these three scripts celery.sh, flower.sh, start.sh

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth &&
./celery.sh"'
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth &&
./start.sh"'
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth &&
./flower.sh"'
```

i also found it `redundant`, because now, `i have 4 scripts`, and with this update, i can start all these 3 terminals from `one script`

`ultimatestarter.sh`

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "activate () { 
                  . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
                  } 
activate 
cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/projectname
celery -A projectname worker -l info"'

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "activate () { 
                  . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
                  } 
activate 
cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/projectname
celery -A projectname flower --port=5555"'

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "activate () { 
                  . /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/venv/bin/activate
                  } 
activate 
cd /Users/oleg/Desktop/auth/projectname
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. figure out, which terminal you'd like to start (I'm using xterm as an example)
2. check your terminal's man page for the actual command to start it with an argument (optionally: To stay open once the command finished)
3. execute the commands in the background (`&`)

For xterm this might be something like

```
xterm -e /bin/bash -ls -c "./celery.sh" &
xterm -e /bin/bash -ls -c "./flower.sh" &
xterm -e /bin/bash -ls -c "./start.sh" &
```

Sprinkle in `pause`, if necessary.

Comment: can you help with figuring out this command for `zsh` terminal? If i do the same with `zsh`, `zsh -e /bin/bash -ls -c "./celery.sh"` it returns error `/bin/bash:1: command not found: \M-J\M-~\M-:\M->`

Comment: is it neccesary to use `&` symbol?  in my case, it works without it

Comment: isn't `zsh` a shell (e.g. alternative to bash) rather than a terminal application (that would run the shell)? For me, the same command works well if I use KDE's `konsole` to stand in for `xterm`

Comment: i'm not sure about the difference

Comment: If you replace `/bin/bash` with `/bin/zsh` it might work. Otherwise check where zsh is installed: `which zsh`.